# specifying more than one character on nmap --ip-options

Tags: nmap

### specifying more than one character on nmap --ip-options

Hi, I'v been on https://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2006/q3/52 a short reference manuel on --ip-options nmap option

I am trying to put more than one option character ex: R T U but got

Not a valid ipv4 address ''

I'v tried difference syntax

nmap --ip-options R T U 172.217.22.142
nmap --ip-options "R T U" 172.217.22.142
nmap --ip-options RTU 172.217.22.142
nmap --ip-options "RTU" 172.217.22.142
nmap --ip-options "R" "T" "U" 172.217.22.142

even thought
nmap --ip-options R 172.217.22.142
nmap --ip-options "R" 172.217.22.142

worked

how can I put more than 1 characrer

Answer (score 1):

From [the firewall/IDS section of the nmap man page](https://nmap.org/book/man-bypass-firewalls-ids.html), "pass the letter R, T, or U to request record-route, record-timestamp, or both options together, respectively".

So you should never need R, T, and U all at the same time. If you want all of that, just use `U`.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please vote on it or accept it. See https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers.